# BufferedImage into OpenCV Mat in Java

Tags: java, opencv, bufferedimage

I've read the article here that suggests what I'm doing should work: [Converting BufferedImage to Mat in opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14958643/converting-bufferedimage-to-mat-in-opencv)

Can anyone tell me why my output is so dramatically different than what's in the top left 10x10 pixels on my desktop?

edit:

original 10x10 image (eclipse logo basically): http://tinypic.com/r/35l5clt/5

after loading into Mat: http://tinypic.com/r/af7w90/5

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException,
        AWTException, IOException {

    byte[] bgrPixelData = ScreenToImage.GetCurrentScreenImage();
    Mat screenFrame = new Mat(10, 10, CvType.CV_8UC3);
    screenFrame.put(0, 0, bgrPixelData);

    // Create a blank output image, that we will draw onto.
    Mat outputFrame = new Mat(screenFrame.size(), CvType.CV_8UC3);

    // Save output and display the openCV Mat image onto the screen.
    ImageToScreen.DrawImageToScreen("c:\\temp\\wtf.png", outputFrame);
}


public class ScreenToImage {

public static byte[] GetCurrentScreenImage() throws AWTException,
        IOException {
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    Dimension d = new Dimension();
    d.height = 10;
    d.width = 10;

    BufferedImage screenShot = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(d));

    BufferedImage bgrScreenshot = new BufferedImage(screenShot.getWidth(),
            screenShot.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
    boolean done = bgrScreenshot.getGraphics().drawImage(screenShot, 0, 0, null);

    return ((DataBufferByte) bgrScreenshot.getRaster().getDataBuffer())
            .getData();
}
}
static {
    System.loadLibrary("opencv_java246");
}

public class ImageToScreen extends JFrame{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public static void DrawImageToScreen(String imgStr, Mat m){
    Highgui.imwrite(imgStr, m);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Screen Capture");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(true);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(imgStr);
    frame.setSize(image.getIconWidth()+10,image.getIconHeight()+35);
    // Draw the Image data into the BufferedImage
    JLabel label1 = new JLabel(" ", image, JLabel.CENTER);
    frame.getContentPane().add(label1);

    frame.validate();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: I get mostly black 10x10 square.. i'll look for a place to upload.

Comment: edited original post to include input and output images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating empty image

```
Mat outputFrame = new Mat(screenFrame.size(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
```

Then you are saving it to file and re-read as `BufferedImage`

```
Highgui.imwrite(imgStr, m);
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(imgStr);
```

Because of that the file contains some random values from memory.
Try to call `ImageToScreen.DrawImageToScreen` with `screenFrame` object and it shoud work.

Also you can create `BufferedImage` directly from `Mat` (without using temporary file):

```
public static BufferedImage createBufferedImage(Mat mat) {
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(mat.width(), mat.height(), BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
    WritableRaster raster = image.getRaster();
    DataBufferByte dataBuffer = (DataBufferByte) raster.getDataBuffer();
    byte[] data = dataBuffer.getData();
    mat.get(0, 0, data);
    return image;
}
```