# Converting BufferedImage to Mat (OpenCV) in Java

Tags: java, image, opencv, image-processing, bufferedimage

I've tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14958643/converting-bufferedimage-to-mat-in-opencv) and have the code below. My program imports images in a BufferedImage format and then displays it to the users. I'm using the [matchingTemplate](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html) function in OpenCV which requires me to convert it to a Mat format.

The code works if I import the image -> convert it to Mat then save the image using imwrite. The program also allows the user to crop an image and then use the [Template matching](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html) to compare it to another image. The issue come when I tried to convert the cropped image to Mat I need to convert it from Int to Byte using this code:

```
im = new BufferedImage(im.getWidth(), im.getHeight(),BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
```

This however results in a black image. But if I get rid of it it only works with imported images and not cropped. What is going on here? I'm certain it is something to do with the coversion process as I have tested the template matching function using read in images.

```
// Convert image to Mat
public Mat matify(BufferedImage im) {
    // Convert INT to BYTE
    //im = new BufferedImage(im.getWidth(), im.getHeight(),BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
    // Convert bufferedimage to byte array
    byte[] pixels = ((DataBufferByte) im.getRaster().getDataBuffer())
            .getData();

    // Create a Matrix the same size of image
    Mat image = new Mat(im.getHeight(), im.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
    // Fill Matrix with image values
    image.put(0, 0, pixels);

    return image;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this method, to actually convert the image to `TYPE_3BYTE_BGR` (your code simply created a blank image of the same size, that is why it was all black).

Usage:

```
// Convert any type of image to 3BYTE_BGR
im = toBufferedImageOfType(im, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);

// Access pixels as in original code
```

And the conversion method:

```
public static BufferedImage toBufferedImageOfType(BufferedImage original, int type) {
    if (original == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("original == null");
    }

    // Don't convert if it already has correct type
    if (original.getType() == type) {
        return original;
    }

    // Create a buffered image
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(original.getWidth(), original.getHeight(), type);

    // Draw the image onto the new buffer
    Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
    try {
        g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);
        g.drawImage(original, 0, 0, null);
    }
    finally {
        g.dispose();
    }

    return image;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up working in opencv's Mat format then converted it a BufferedImage to display to the user, which required a lot of re-working methods. But I'll give this a try when I get a chance.

Comment: Is `pOriginal` supposed to be `original`?

Comment: @Sortofabeginner: Yes, well spotted. :-) Thanks. Edited now.