# Convert OpenCV Mat from and to a JavaFX Image

Tags: opencv, javafx

Since OpenCV 3 the Highgui class doesn't exist anymore and the existing tutorials for OpenCV in Java which use Highgui don't apply anymore.

What is the proper way to convert a Mat to a JavaFX image and vice versa?

From my searches I found this for the Mat -> Image conversion which seems to work:

```
public static Image mat2Image(Mat frame) {
    // create a temporary buffer
    MatOfByte buffer = new MatOfByte();
    // encode the frame in the buffer, according to the PNG format
    Imgcodecs.imencode(".png", frame, buffer);
    // build and return an Image created from the image encoded in the
    // buffer
    return new Image(new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer.toArray()));
}
```

I've also found solutions for Image to Mat conversion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21740729/converting-bufferedimage-to-mat-opencv-in-java) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/752511/How-to-Convert-Mat-to-BufferedImage-Vice-Versa). But they don't seem to be as convenient as Imgcodecs.imencode and I guess there would be an api for the conversion, but I can't find it.

How do you convert an Image to Mat with OpenCV 3?