# OpenCV camera image shows bluish

Tags: java, android, opencv

I'm using the below code to get an image from the camera, but the camera image shows colours differently.

```
public Mat mat = new Mat();
private BufferedImage img;
private byte[] dat;

    public void getSpace(Mat mat) {
            this.mat = mat;
            int w = mat.cols(), h = mat.rows();
            if (dat == null || dat.length != w * h * 3)
                dat = new byte[w * h * 3];
            if (img == null || img.getWidth() != w || img.getHeight() != h || img.getType() != BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR)
                img = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
        }

        public BufferedImage getImage(Mat mat) {
            getSpace(mat);
            mat.get(0, 0, dat);
            img.getRaster().setDataElements(0, 0, mat.cols(), mat.rows(), dat);
            return img;
        }
```

[image]

Comment: looks like red and blue channels are interchanged (green light is still green but blue light is red and redish areas are bluish)

Comment: your code is strange. is "img" a global variable?

Comment: @Micka no it isn't public, I included the fields now as well.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your images is of type RGB instead of BRG? In that case you would have exchanged red and blue colour. Try changing `TYPE_3BYTE_BGR`into `TYPE_3BYTE_RGB`

[EDIT] Sorry, I am only on the Python side of OpenCV. What has happend is that you accidentially switched channels B and R (1st and 3rd layer of your image matrix), you need to switch this back. Exchange it in the matrix if necessary.

That link might help: [Converting BufferedImage to Mat in opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14958643/converting-bufferedimage-to-mat-in-opencv)

[EDIT2] Have a look at the comment of Micka below

Comment: unfortunately, TYPE_3BYTE_RGB doesn't exist. the only rgb that exists is TYPE_INT_RGB which doesn't work.

Comment: you can try to convert the opencv mat from rgb to bgr. c++ code would be cv::cvtColor (mat,mat, CV_RGB2BGR) maybe you xan convert that?