# How to convert BufferedImage to Mat (OpenCV)

Tags: java, opencv, javacv

I'm using this library

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
    <artifactId>javacv</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

OpenCV version appears to be 3.2

I found [same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14958643/converting-bufferedimage-to-mat-in-opencv) question with accepted answer here on stackoverflow, but it appears to be relevant to older versions of API or other library.

This code doesn't work for me...

```
public Mat bufferedImageToMat(BufferedImage bi) {
    Mat mat = new Mat(bi.getHeight(), bi.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
    byte[] data = ((DataBufferByte) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
    mat.put(0, 0, data);
    return mat;
}
```

...because Mat class doesn't have method

```
mat.put(0, 0, data);
```

How to achieve same goal with bytedeco javacv 1.3.2 ?

p.s. can somebody guide me to documentation that I can use to find answers myself, so far I wasn't able to find good API reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with this method (works for color BufferedImage)

```
public Mat bufferedImageToMat(BufferedImage bi) {
    Mat mat = new Mat(bi.getHeight(), bi.getWidth(), CV_8UC(3));

    int r, g, b;
    UByteRawIndexer indexer = mat.createIndexer();
    for (int y = 0; y < bi.getHeight(); y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < bi.getWidth(); x++) {
            int rgb = bi.getRGB(x, y);

            r = (byte) ((rgb >> 0) & 0xFF);
            g = (byte) ((rgb >> 8) & 0xFF);
            b = (byte) ((rgb >> 16) & 0xFF);

            indexer.put(y, x, 0, r);
            indexer.put(y, x, 1, g);
            indexer.put(y, x, 2, b);
        }
    }
    indexer.release();
    return mat;
}
```